# How to create a generic (void) JQueryDeferred object using TypeScript and jquery.d.ts

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-deferred

I am using the jquery.d.ts that comes from the DefinitelyTyped repo (using tsd). It seems to be the "official" jquery typing as the license header says it is created by Microsoft.

Now, I occasionally need to create a deferred object that does not need to pass any arguments to it's `.resolve()` or `.reject()` methods and I can't figure out how do this with the static typing.

I am currently using a workaround at this point: I am creating the deferred via `JQueryDeferred<boolean> dfd = $.Deferred()` and resolve it via `dfd.resolve(false)` although I wouldn't really need to pass a boolean value. From the jquery.d.ts file I can only find a `JQueryDeferred<T>` declartion, but not a generic one (sth. like `JQueryDeferred<void>` but this is not valid TypeScript syntax).

How is it done "the proper way" (TM)?

Comment: Strange, the [specification (PDF)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) says on page 25 that `Void is permitted as a type argument to a generic type or
function`. Maybe it's only a casing issue? Did you try `JQueryDeferred<Void>`, capital `V`?

Comment: Using Void with capital V gives an error saying "Symbol 'Void' not found" and WebStorm (which has TS syntax highlighting) marks it immediately as red for error. Using void with lowercase v gives the strange error: `error TS2012: Cannot convert 'JQueryDeferred<{}>' to 'JQueryDeferred<void>'`

Comment: Not a casing issue, then. I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but the spec says the only subtypes of `void` are the `Null` type and the `Undefined` type. Clearly something else is used as the generic argument there. For what it's worth, can you try `JQueryDeferred<any>`?

Comment: JQueryDeferred<any> will work of course but has different semantic - that says that the first argument passed to `.resolve` is of type any (which is basically any type, like the VARIANT type in VisualBasic).

Comment: Are we talking about [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) d.ts file? Because the only JQueryDeferred I can find there is an interface so I don't understand why `new JQueryDeferred` works for you. This compiles with no errors in Visual Studio: `var dfd: JQueryDeferred<void> = jQuery.Deferred<void>();dfd.resolve();`

Comment: You are of course right, I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, but have you tried `JQueryDeferred<void> = jQuery.Deferred<void>()` ? Because that error message you posted pops up for me as well when I leave out the second generic as in `jQuery.Deferred()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include the generic `<void>` in the call to `jQuery.Deferred<void>()` as well.

The following code should compile without errors:

```
var dfd: JQueryDeferred<void> = jQuery.Deferred<void>();
dfd.resolve();
```

I don't know why `JQueryDeferred<boolean> dfd = $.Deferred()` doesn't cause an error as well though.

By the way: Even if you stay with your workaround, you don't have to pass a boolean to `dfd.resolve()` since `resolve`'s parameter `value` is optional (as indicated by the `?`).

Comment: That works. I don't know either why `$.Deferred()` works for the right hand side of the assignment, though.